# How to get indexes of repetitive elements in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So for example, I need to find the `count` of every iterable `element` in arr `newArr` that is repetetive to the previous element.

For now I make the function, that `filter` my uniques `elements` from doubled, but I also need to catch the every `index` of these `elements`, that are repetetive... For now I got only the `last index` of the last repetetive `element`.

```js
var newArr = ["abc", "abc", "abc", "d", "et", "d", "et", "zzz"];
function calc(newArr) {
    var obj = {};
    newArr.map((newAr, index) => {

        obj[newAr] = index; // only last index for each repetetive elem
                            // for "abc" it must be an array of [0,1,2]
    });
    return obj;
};

console.log(calc(newArr));
```

Comment: what means iterable element? the array which is iterable element, or the element itself? in which kind would you like to iterate an element and waht is the wanted result of it?

Answer (score 3):

Initialise `obj[newAr]` with an array, and push the indexes.

**Note:** Use `Array.forEach()` instead of `Array.map()`, because forEach is used for side effects.

```js
var newArr = ["abc", "abc", "abc", "d", "et", "d", "et", "zzz"];

function calc(newArr) {
  var obj = {};

  newArr.forEach((newAr, index) => {
    // init with array if the key is falsy (undefined in this case)
    obj[newAr] = obj[newAr] || []; 
    
    // push the current index into the array
    obj[newAr].push(index);
  });


  return obj;
};


console.log(calc(newArr));
```

Comment: Can you please explaine this string more -                     `obj[newAr] = obj[newAr] || [];` . So why we put in the `value` of the `key` - `obj[newAr]` - (the value `key` of seft)?

Comment: I'm using [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) to assign a new array if `obj[newAr]` is `undefined`. If it's defined, I'm assigning the same reference, which actually does nothing. You can replace it with an `if`: `if(!obj[newAr]) obj[newAr] = []`.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```js
var newArr = ["abc", "abc", "abc", "d", "et", "d", "et", "zzz"];
function calc(newArr) {
    var obj = {};
    newArr.map((newAr, index) => {
            obj[newAr] = obj[newAr] || []; 
            obj[newAr].push(index);
        });
    return obj;
};

console.log(calc(newArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could spread the collected indices or take an empty array for spreading ([spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) and take the actual element for the indices object.

BTW, after a block statement or a function body, you need no semicolon, instead of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) take [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), because you need to iterate the items, but you do not use the returned array of `map`.

```js
function calc(array) {
    var indices = {};
    array.forEach((v, i) => indices[v] = [...indices[v] || [], i]);
    return indices;
}

var newArr = ["abc", "abc", "abc", "d", "et", "d", "et", "zzz"];

console.log(calc(newArr));
```